# primefaces push not working in Safari using AWS Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, primefaces, safari, websocket, push

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1, JSF 2.1 and tomcat 7 and my application is in AWS. atmosphere version 2.2.2.

I am not able to use push functionality in Safari 5.1.7.

We have configured the AWS to enable push based on [Primeface push with AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108966/primeface-push-with-aws) , [Websocket with Tomcat 7 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460832/websocket-with-tomcat-7-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) and [Creation of .ebextensions folder in aws elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797651/creation-of-ebextensions-folder-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk).

Push is working in all other browsers.

I tried the solution provided in [primepush on Tomcat 7 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929606/primepush-on-tomcat-7-not-working) which was unsuccessful.

Safari console shows [image]

Any help is appreciated..

Update1: one option is to try non secure websockets when safari browser is detected (from http://blog.marcon.me/post/24874118286/secure-websockets-safari). If so, the question is how to make the primefaces's push to select non secure web socket?

Update2: tried implementing SSL to see if push was not working in Safari due to our self signed certificate. that also didnot seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurred due to a missing configuration the web.xml.
On analysing tomcat's log (catalina.out), found an error when Safari was trying to connnect to tomcat, `ERROR org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported.`

On searching with this error, found a solution from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/atmosphere-framework/D5-yrW6NzLU

Added `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to shiroFilter in web.xml like

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </filter>
```

Using this, Safari 5.1.7 was able to use push functionality.

Hope this help somebody else like it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Safari 5.1.7 is very old ... here https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Safari-and-WebSockets-Issues is documented that there was issues with 5.1.5. I don't think that there was fix from .5 to .7 for that.

Comment: but for windows os , they have not provided any other higher versions of Safari..

Comment: I know, for me is safari for windows like internet explorer< V7 ... a not supported browser-plattform. Maybe you should also think about it.